# How to make a parent --> node relationship in css?

Tags: css, cross-browser, logic

Can someone help me to fix this `parent -> node` relationship in css.
To make it clear, let's see some example:

[Css: Parent and child relationship](http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/KyQNY/)

Rules:

1. All first Parent should be colored in Blue
2. All sub parent should be colored in Orange
3. All child should be colored in Green

It is considered as a parent if it has 1 or more sub node/child.
It is considered as a child if it has no sub node/child.

It means:

```
Parent1-child2-Subparent1-child1
```

and

```
Parent1-child2-Subparent1-child2
```

should be colored in green.
No script is allowed. Only css, and as much as possible, should be cross browser compatible. Please help, I can't figure out the logic of it.

Comment: I believe you can't do this, generally, since there's no CSS selector for "having no descendants". If you can narrow down the scope (will you always have exactly 4 levels?), or if you can put a distinct class on child nodes, then it may be possible,

Comment: I also thought of that. Hmmm... if this is not possible in css, I have no choice but to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chowlett

As I always believe, code is not the law, but the logic.
Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/JzRVt/)

I just added:

```
a + .jqtree-title
```

here:

```
#tree1 .jqtree-tree > .jqtree-folder .jqtree-folder div  a + .jqtree-title
{
    color:orange;
}
```

And everything works fine even on a deep tree hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

There's no selector for this in the current [CSS Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/) module. However, the [Selectors Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) module offers a method to  determine *"the subject of a selector"*.

That being said, there's no browser that implements that behaviour, as CSS4:Selectors are still a working draft. You'll have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. But I got using adjacent selector in css